# Преинкремент и постинкремент

Tags: c#

Задали вопрос на учебе, что больше потребляет ресурсов ++i или i++. Самостоятельно инфо не нашёл, прошу подсказать где искать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/861112/1991579 TL:DR - нет разницы никакой.

Comment: ++i в теории может быть меньше. на практике одинаково.

Comment: @pavel: Это в C++ есть разница, в C# нету.

Comment: @VladD основным языком препода является С++, может он не знает что в C# разницы нету. Подскажите в чем разница в плюсах?

Comment: Вместо того, что бы обращать внимание на действительно важные вещи, на учебе говорят о таком...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно [спецификации языка](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#postfix-increment-and-decrement-operators), разница между пре- и постинкрементом состоит в том, что при вычислении выражения значением результат является в одном случае старое, а в другом — новое значение инкрементируемой переменной. В случае простого применения в форме `x++;` (например, такое часто встречается в циклах) возвращаемое значение не используется, и смысл обеих форм строго одинаков, так что они компилируются в одинаковый объектный код.

Даже если оператор инкремента переопределён, разницы нет, т. к. (в отличие от C++) нет возможности иметь различные определения для пре- и постинкрементов.

Откуда растут ноги у этого вопроса? А вот откуда. В древние времена были наивные компиляторы языка C (и, возможно, C++), которые не умели оптимизировать код. И если они компилировали прямолинейно, то код получался таким:

```
// x++
int temp = x;
x = x + 1;
// результат = temp; но он не нужен, так что он отбрасывается
```

и

```
// ++x;
x = x + 1;
// результат = x; но он не нужен, так что он отбрасывается
```

Ваш преподаватель, вероятно, слыхал об этом, и ждёт от вас ответа о том, что необходимо ручной оптимизацией убрать ненужную временную переменную. Он неправ, отстал от реальности на вечность и тянет вас в эпоху трилобитов.

В реальности последние как минимум 10 лет компиляторы умеют делать оптимизации намного лучше людей, и в частности прекрасно умеют выбрасывать никому не нужные временные переменные. Так что разницы в сгенерированном коде просто не будет, что можно видеть даже для C++ [здесь](http://godbolt.org/g/6uSrvU).* (Если вы, конечно, не отключите оптимизации.)

---

Теперь с точки зрения промышленной практики. Если вам нужно ускорить выполнение вашей программы, нанооптимизации наподобие использования преинкремента вместо постинкремента — даже если бы они и давали выигрыш в один такт процессора — никогда не являются нужным средством. Оптимизируйте ваши алгоритмы и структуры данных, переходите от квадратичных алгоритмов к линейным и логарифмическим. Не экономьте копейки, это не окупается.

---

*Например, из таких двух функций:

```
volatile int x; // угадайте, что будет, если убрать volatile :-P

int pre(int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        x = i;
}

int post(int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        x = i;
}
```

gcc 7.2 с ключом `-O3` производит

```
pre(int):
  test edi, edi
  jle .L2
  xor eax, eax
.L3:
  mov DWORD PTR x[rip], eax
  add eax, 1
  cmp edi, eax
  jne .L3
.L2:
  rep ret
post(int):
  test edi, edi
  jle .L6
  xor eax, eax
.L8:
  mov DWORD PTR x[rip], eax
  add eax, 1
  cmp edi, eax
  jne .L8
.L6:
  xor eax, eax
  ret
```

А с ключом `-Os` вообще

```
pre(int):
  xor eax, eax
.L3:
  cmp eax, edi
  jge .L2
  mov DWORD PTR x[rip], eax
  inc eax
  jmp .L3
.L2:
  ret
post(int):
  jmp pre(int)
```

Comment: А будет ли разница, если инкремент участвует в дереве выражений и возвращаемое значение используется при вычислениях?

Comment: @AlexKrass: Конечно будет, у них же в этом случае разная семантика! То есть, при замене одного на другой получится разный числовой результат, так что код одинаковым быть не может.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. После этого ДЗ, мне задали ДЗ с побитовыми операциями, например реализовать умножение при помощи сдвигов. Мне кажется что мы не тем занимаемся, хотя по правде говоря побитовыми операциями я никогда не пользовался и даже не знаю актуальны ли они. Я вижу что Вы очень опытный человек в C# и не только, подскажите пожалуйста на это стоит тратить время или может мне стоит поискать другие курсы или мы все таки идем в правильном направлении? Очень нуждаюсь в совете практикующего специалиста.

Comment: @Winteriscoming: Ну, смотрите. Низкоуровневые вещи наподобие реализации умножения битовыми операциями на самом деле интересны, т. к. это основы. Вам скорее всего никогда не придётся применять это на практике (разве что если будете разрабатывать собственное железо). Но знать это неплохо.

Comment: @Winteriscoming: Так что вот эта часть знаний — не самая плохая. Но стоит ко всему в любом случае относиться критично, и переспрашивать (например, тут, на сайте), если что-то непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

В C# разницы между пост- и преинкрементом нет, в C++ (отвечая на Ваш комментарий с ?) ситуация следующая: как правило, постинкремент реализуется посредством преинкремента и возвращает первоначальное значение переменной. Каноническая форма постинкремента:

```
T T::operator++(int)
{
    T old(*this);
    ++*this;
    return old;
}
```

Как видите, создается временная переменная `old`. Каноническая форма преинкремента:

```
T& T::operator++()
{
    // increment your object here
    return *this;
}
```

Поэтому быстрее будет работать преинкремент.

Comment: Каноническая форма преинкремента какая-то рекурсивная :)

Comment: @VladD полагаю нынешние компиляторы действительно создают одинаковый объектный код, фраза «работать быстрее» взята мной из красной книжки Саттера, сами понимаете, какой это год;) Кстати, проверил на php - преинкремент быстрее работает

Comment: @Jenssen: Современные компиляторы очень стараются генерировать код не тупо построчно, а пытаются понять семантику кода. Для кода с одинаковой семантикой компилятор старается сгенерировать одинаковый (потому что оптимальный) объектный код. А PHP — ну, значит, их компилятор застрял в триасе.