# Как работает x = x++ и x = ++x?

Tags: c++

Пусть x = 5. Тогда в обоих случаях cout << x даст 6. Но в случае x = x++, кажется, что работать должно так:

1. Отрабатывает x++: заведется переменная y, куда положится 5. Затем x увеличится на 1. Итого возвращается значение 5, а x = 6.
2. Отрабатывает присваивание: переменной x=6 присваивается значение 5.
   Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка в понимании работы?

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ravesli.com/urok-40-inkrement-dekrement-pobochnye-effekty/)

Comment: [Здесь](https://josephmansfield.uk/articles/c++-sequenced-before-graphs.html) неплохое описание

Comment: @dmtr : спасибо большое! Стало понятно.

Comment: @Andrey SV спасибо большое! Стало понятно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преинкремент и постинкремент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740651/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82), в вопросе на примере C# разбирается, но там ноги растут из C, поэтому актуально, и объяснение хорошее.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какая разница между i++ и ++i?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055621/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-i-%d0%b8-i)

Answer (score 3):

До C++17 оба варианта вызывают неопределенное поведение, см. [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Начиная с C++17, насколько я понял, `x = x++` не меняет значение `x`, а `x = ++x` увеличивает его на 1.

Объяснение в вопросе правильное. Если ваш компилятор дает другой результат, то или он не поддерживает C++17, или в нем баг.

Последние GCC и Clang выдают правильный результат, хотя почему-то с предупреждениями.

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрим первый пример x = ++x;

Сначала будет посчитано значение справа от знака присваивания, а затем будет выполнено само присваивание.

1) Выполнение преинкремента. Значение x увеличивается на единицу и возвращается новое значение x-а.

2) Выполняется оператор присваивания.

т.е можно расписать вот так:

```
x = x + 1;  (преинкремент)

x = x;  (присваивание)
```

Если изначально x равнялся 5, то его значение, после этих операций, будет 6

Второй пример x = x++;

1) Выполнение постинкремента. Говорят, что сначала возвращается значение x, а потом увеличение x-а на 1. На самом деле снимается копия с переменной x, происходит инкремент, возвращение старого значения x (копии)

2) Выполняется оператор присваивания.

т.е можно расписать вот так:

```
auto y = x;

x = x + 1;  (постинкремент)

x = y;  (операция вернула y (копию старого значения x))
```

Т.е если в начале x = 5, то операция постинкремента вернет 5 (хотя значение x-а в этот момент равно 6-ти), а затем вызовется оператор присваивания и x (в котором все еще лежит 6) затерется результатом операции постинкремента (ну т.е. 5)

В результате во втором примере в x лежит 5